# How to use flux with meteor

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flux

I am starting on a new project and I want to keep my code as structured as possible. I was planning on using the flux pattern for the front-end but it feels like the event driven process that flux follows, goes against the grain of the reactionary way that meteor handles data and view updates.

Here is an example of what one of my stores might look like using flux and meteor

```js
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'
import appDispatcher from '../Dispatcher'
import Meteor from 'meteor/meteor'

class TaskStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.tasks = [];
        Meteor.subscribe('tasks');
    }

    addTask(task) {
        Meteor.addTask(task)
        this.tasks = Meteor.findAll();
    }

    getTasks() {
        return this.tasks
    }

}





const taskStore = new TaskStore();

appDispatcher.register((payload) => {
    switch (payload.actionName) {
        case 'CLICK':
            taskStore.addTask(payload.newItem.action);
            taskStore.emit('ADD_TASK');
            break;
        default:
    }
});

export default taskStore
```

It's pretty straight forward, the store responds to the dispatcher by adding a task to the mongo database, then updates the local model with the data from the database and emits a change event. The view would respond by calling the `getTasks()` method and updating the state.

This works, but it doesn't feel very reactionary. I need a separate method exposed for finding all the tasks for example, where as in the documentation for react views that meteor provides, they have their own special function that wraps components and updates the props of the component whenever the data changes

```
export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('tasks');

  return {
    tasks: Tasks.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch(),
    incompleteCount: Tasks.find({ checked: { $ne: true } }).count()
})
```

This seems to be the way that meteor was designed. Views react to data changes and update in real time across all platforms, and I'm just not certain if my implementation of the flux pattern is the best way to stay true to that design, or if I should even bother trying to stay true to that design at all.

As a disclaimer, I'm still extremely new to both the flux pattern, and the Meteor framework.

Comment: Do you even need Flux? I got caught up in the trendiness of Redux awhile ago, and integrated it into my project. Months later, now that I look at it, I question if I even needed to use it at all. Redux & Flux are good for things like global UI state, e.g. "is this sidebar expanded or not." But then again, you could just as easily use Meteor's client-only collections to have a global reactive way to maintain a UI state.

Comment: That's a good point. I may not need flux at all, I just want to keep my code maintainable and testable throughout, and have a clear idea of where everything is happening. That being said, the two patterns feel contradictory and I may just leave flux out all together.

Comment: As things progressed in my project, I found that I didn't really need the global UI state too much, and I was mostly using Redux as an action dispatcher. But I could just as easily have functions in their own JavaScript files grouped by concern, and then `import` those into my React components in order to carry out certain operations. Or I might develop an action dispatch package.. hmm. Anyway, some food for thought.